# Same class mapped to multiple collections?

Tags: java, database, mongodb, morphia

I want to have template objects for a class in the database and owned/altered by clients of these objects both stored in a database. To do this I can figure out 3 options.

- 2 classes where the owned class takes a template object to construct itself. This will create 2 nearly identical classes and constructing from the template object does not feel right to me.
- The same class stored in 2 collections to differentiate from template and owned object. The template objects will have one redundant field that references to a client ID for a owned object. I am not sure if I can turn off writing Indexed fields to DB if they are not initialized. Also, I cannot seem to find a way to store the same class in a different collection. I am using `Datastore.save(..)` to write to DB and it seems collection name is chosen by class name. I can alter this at class level but that still means I cannot create 2 different collections for this class.
- One class, one collection. I could use the `ownerId` reference field to specify the object is a template. However, the collection of owned objects will grow rapidly and templates need to be accessed often so this creates overhead.

There seems to be `AdvancedDatastore`, I have not used it but it seems to have `AdvancedDatastore.save(String collection, T entity)`. However, it does not have a signature like that for update, delete and many other methods. So I am not sure how to properly use this in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated my `Datastore` implementation to a custom `BasisDAO` implementation where I can use `AdvancedDatastore` to supply a collection name. Here is what it looks like:

```
public class UserDAO extends BasicDAO<User, String> {
    private final String collectionName;

    public UserDAO(MongoClient mongoClient, Morphia morphia, String dbName, String collectionName) {
        super(mongoClient, morphia, dbName);
        this.collectionName = collectionName;
    }

    @Override
    public Key<User> save(User entity) {

        return ((AdvancedDatastore)getDatastore()).save(collectionName, entity);
    }

    @Override
    public WriteResult delete(User entity) {
        return ((AdvancedDatastore)getDatastore()).delete(collectionName, User.class, entity.getId());
    }

    public User getByName(String userName) {
        return ((AdvancedDatastore)getDatastore()).createQuery(collectionName, User.class).field("name").equal(userName).get();
    }
}
```

Using this class I am able to create multiple collections for the same class.

**edit**

The problem is, if you use a method from the base class that is not overwritten it will work in the default collection (class name by default). Since there does not seem to be a DAO that supports collection names I think it's better to just roll your own DAO from scratch with a `AdvancedDatastore`. You can implement the DAO interface and write all it's methods yourself ff you need it's contract or full functionality.